# Creating my Custom Unique Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in my SQL Server. Currently I am using the identity column to uniquely identify each record but my changing needs required a unique key generated in a certain format (as specified by my client). I have tried to generate the unique key from my application by appending a unique integer (that is incremented on every insert) to the format specified my client is not satisfied with my current solution. 
It would be great if I can be directed to a better technique to solve my problem rather then my current solution.

The format is like:

```
PRN-YEAR-MyAppGeneratedInt
```

Comment: @BHouse `NEW()`? That isn't a T-SQL keyword.

Comment: It would be great to know data format.

Comment: @Larnu A typo, corrected it :)

Comment: The format is like PRN-YEAR-MyAppGeneratedInt

Comment: Could you deal with a computed column?

Comment: So Client is not happy with AppGeneratedInt , how does client want the data or any preferred datattype

Comment: the client is not happy with my current approach to tackling the problem through the application code @BHouse

Comment: Try this way `PRN-Year-Newsequentialid`, Using instead of int in end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, keep the current `identity` column.  That is the best way for *you* to identify and manage rows in the table.

If the client needs another unique key, then add it.  Presumably, it will be a string (given that it has a "format").  You can possibly create the key as a generated column.  Alternatively, you may need to use a trigger to calculate it.

In general, integers are better for identity columns, even if end users never see them.  Here are some advantages:

- They encode the ordering of row insertion in the database.  You can, for instance, get the last inserted row.
- They are more efficient for foreign key references (because numbers are fixed-length and generally shorter than strings).
- They make it possible to directly address a row, when data needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SEQUENCE to serve your purpose which were introduced in SQL Server 2012. A real detailed explanation about SEQUENCE can be found [here](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6372779328366829568).

Hope this helps :)

As per you specified in the comments the format let me also give you an example that how you can solve your problem using a sequence:

First create a sequence like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SeqName
AS int
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CYCLE 
CACHE
```

Next you can use this sequence to generate your desired unique key in you app program.

1. Get the next value for sequence "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SeqName;"
2. Create a string using the value like :`String key= "PRN"+year+SeqValue;`
3. Finally store this string as your unique key in your Insert statement.

You can write the application code as per you need :)

Comment: The result will still be an integer.  Care to elaborate on how this would be useful?

Comment: The link you shared requires linkedin login can you please share another one @Tayyab

Comment: I'll share one.  https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=gUGZWt_dF8LF8ge4rKiICw&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: I am afraid that I can't. Yet why don't you create a linked in id. It actually might be helpful for you both the link I shared and linked in itself :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table) and just append the identity

```
('Custom_'+CONVERT(varchar(10),iden))
```