# Auto Generating Unique Key Not Consistent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a unique key in the following format:

ABC123456

So for example it would start at ABC000001 and finish at ABC999999, basically first three characters are ABC and then 6 numbers.

I have the following query currently:

```
  SELECT 
    'ABC' + CAST(REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(RTRIM(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))))+ (SELECT Counter from Counters)) + RTRIM(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + (SELECT Counter from Counters)) as CHAR(9)) as InvoiceNumber,
    ID,
    RandomNumber
 from
    RandomNumbers
```

Here is some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Counters](
    [Counter] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Counters]
           ([Counter])
     VALUES
           (0)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RandomNumbers](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [RandomNumber] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

with randowvalues
    as(
       select 1 id, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*100 as int) randomnumber
        union  all
        select id + 1, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*100 as int)  randomnumber
        from randowvalues
        where 
          id < 1000
      )

Insert into RandomNumbers
(
ID,
RandomNumber
)
select *
from randowvalues
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

You'll see it works fine initially, but if you run this for example:

```
Update Counters
Set Counter = 1
```

and then re-run the main query, it throws the numbering out. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How you are trying to create this number? Your formula looks a bit odd and what is the purpose of `Counters`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating my Custom Unique Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068740/creating-my-custom-unique-key)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  If you just want to generate such numbers, you can use a sequence.  If you want to add a field like this to a table, there are better ways.

Comment: `Row_Number`, hmm. Can a row be deleted?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - primary reason I didn't think of sequence is that I need to be able to able to reset it back to 0 and it be easy to maintain by non-sql people.

Comment: @HABO - no rows can be deleted.

Comment: @Philip . . . sequences have those capabilities.  Further, they are documented and supported by the database.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @GordonLinoff, I've gone with your approach and it is working perfectly. The CYCLE command serves my purpose well too.

Answer (score 1):

Using `STUFF()` function:

```
with
    cte
as
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + (SELECT Counter from Counters) as InvNo,
        ID,
        RandomNumber,
        'ABC000000' as SampleNo
    from
        RandomNumbers
)
select
    stuff(SampleNo, (Len(SampleNo) - Len(InvNo)) + 1, Len(SampleNo), InvNo) as InvoiceNumber,
    ID,
    RandomNumber
from
    cte;
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad - will test it out.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one, it would be better if you have an `IDENTITY` column there

```
SELECT STUFF('ABC000000',
             10 - LEN( CAST(RN AS VARCHAR) ),
             LEN(CAST(RN AS VARCHAR)),
             CAST(RN AS VARCHAR)
       ) GenKey,
       SomeCols
FROM
(
   SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SomeCols) RN --Simulate IDENTITY column if you have one it would be better
   FROM YourTable 
) T;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----------+----------+
|  GenKey   | SomeCols |
+-----------+----------+
| ABC000001 | SomeData |
| ABC000002 | SomeData |
| ABC000003 | SomeData |
| ABC000004 | SomeData |
| ABC000005 | SomeData |
| ABC000006 | SomeData |
| ABC000007 | SomeData |
| ABC000008 | SomeData |
| ABC000009 | SomeData |
| ABC000010 | SomeData |
| …         |          |
+-----------+----------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6b162a82f41f3451203aa8f376ae973)**

If you already have an `IDENTITY` column, then it would be better and get the right `GenKey` even some rows deleted from `YourTable` and even `YourTable` has more than `999999` rows, here is a **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3224442af08e501a6bc7bfb3ec0ff352)** simulate this situation.

Comment: Thanks @Sami - will test it out :)